# Best way to get all model fileds

Tags: python, django, mongodb

What is the best way to get the list of all fields of a model:

I use:

```
list_of_model_field = Mymodel_meta.get_fields()
```

is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but if you just want the names then use a loop:

```
list_of_model_field = [x.name for x in Mymodel._meta.get_fields()]
```

For verbose name

```
list_of_model_field = [x.verbose_name for x in Mymodel._meta.get_fields()]
```

More information can be found in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model).

Comment: thank's a lot for your answer, actually I use names and verbose names, I updated my question.  Can I do it without using "_meta"

Comment: Please see the updated answer. I do not think you can do that without `_meta`.

Comment: You could use `Mymodel.__dict__` to see all the attributes including the fields. But it is not clean, and FYI `_meta` does it better to show every fields even with hidden fields or reverse relation fields.